# SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 install still not 11.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, sql-server-express

I run the SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 install and it succeeds. After I have rebooted my computer, I do a

```
select @@version
```

But still I only have version 11.0.21600.64. I have tried this on two computers now, still the same result.

The file I am running is: `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: Do you have more than one instance (run `sqlcmd -l` at a command prompt, for instance one of dev/test machines shows as `ABT`, `ABT\EXPR` and `ABT\S2008R2` in that list as it has three instances) and if so how are you connecting? You might have upgraded the default instance only and be connecting to another one (or vice versa).

Comment: I downloaded the SQL server Service Pack 1 instead, and then it found my instance..Seems like I cant run the express SP1 version and I rather need the SQL server service pack 1 file.

Comment: 11.0.21600.64 certainly doesn't look right in any case. And when you apply a service pack, you will have either 11.0.3000 (SP1) or 11.0.5058 (SP2, recommended). Not sure why you expect 11.1.

Answer (score 2):

The [full Express version (with SP1 included)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) is for installing a new instance, not for applying a service pack to existing instances. Sounds like perhaps you now have a second instance of SQL Express (no idea without seeing your configuration manager or services applet).

At this point you should download Service Pack ***2*** (not 1) to apply to existing instances, regardless of edition:

[Download SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43340)

(And perhaps clean up the extra instance, if in fact you did install a second instance inadvertently.)